# HTML text.innerHTML animated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code right now:

```js
function change()
{
    text = document.getElementById("click");
 text.innerHTML = "other text<br>other line";
}
```

```html
<a onclick="change()" id="click">Nav Item</a>
```

I would like to change text just like now, but with a slide down animation. Something like this, but the other text slides down over the Click me text.

```js
function showAdvice() {
 $("#text").hide();
  var choose = "text<br>other text";
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = choose;
  $("#text").slideDown();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="showAdvice()">Click me!</a>
<p id="text"></p>
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function change()
{
    $('#click').fadeOut(200, function(){
      $("#click").css('height', '0px');
      $("#click").text("other text<br>other line").show().animate({height: '10px'}, "600");
    });
     
    //$("#click").slideDown(5000);
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="change()" id="click">Nav Item</a>
```